Euclidean Diameter of $G-$ translates of Fundamental domain goes to $0.$ for a Fuchsian group $G$
Lemma : Let $G=\{Id, g_1,g_2,...\}$ be a Fuchsian group acting on $\mathbb{U}$ , where $\mathbb{U}$ is the upper half plane  and $F$ be locally finite fundamental region for $G.$ Then the Euclidean Diameter of $g_n(F)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ .
Fuchsian groups are nothing but the discrete subgroup of $PSl(2,\mathbb{R}).$
Proof of the above fact is given in the book " Fuchsian Groups " by Svetlana Katok. page 103 , lemma 4.5.3  .
My  1st question : is this true for the action of the Fuchsian group in the upper half plane .
For example if we take the group  generated by parabolic element $\langle z\to z+1\rangle$ and if we take the infinite rectangle bounded by $z=1/2$ and $z=-1/2$  as a Fundamental domain for this particular Fuchsian group ,then the above fact is not true ? Am I correct ?
2nd Question : So the proof given in Katok's Book is the following : Assume that the above Lemma is not true .  Then there is a subsequence $n_k$ and points $z_k,w_k\in g_{n_k}(F)$ such that  $ z_k\to z $ and $w_k\to w $ with $d(z,w)> 0$. Clearly $z,w$ can not lie in the interior of the unit ball ,since this contradicts the locally finiteness property of $F$. So they belong to the boundary of the unit disc . Upto this is fine for me .
Now  Claim: $g_{n_k}(F) $ accumulate on the geodesic $[z,w]$ . Sice $[z,w]$ is compact this can not happen , this also contradicts the local finiteness assumtion.
I don't understand the above claim . It is true that $[z,w]$ lie in the interior of unit disc except two end points .

That's correct.

Sir , In the proof I have one doubt , why $g_{n_k}(F)$ accumulate on the geodesic $[z,w]$  If you have seen the proof in Katok , Can you please explain a bit ?

If your actual question is different and more detailed that what you posted, you should hit the edit button and describe what you actually want to know.

Okay sir , let me edit the question .

But make sure that you include enough information that readers can understand what you are asking (without forcing readers to go look for a book they might not own).

You are right and Katok's claim is obviously false, the most famous example is the modular group. There are other mistakes in the book as well.

Katok probably had in mind the unit disk model of the hyperbolic plane (in which case the result follows from local finiteness).

Can you explain my second doubt ?

The second part of the proof is also wrong, compactness is not really the point here. You should include the exact definition of the fundamental region used by Katok. Most importantly, does she assume convexity?

I checked: She does not even assume that fundamental regions are connected. With this definition, Lemma 4.5.3 is false even if one uses the unit disk model of the hyperbolic plane. It is true if one assumes convexity of $F$, maybe it is also true if one assumes connectivity of $F$, I am not sure about this. My suggestion is not to use this book as your primary source for learning the subject.

Which book is ideal for reading Fuchsian Groups?

I do not know about "ideal" (it probably does not exist) but better choices are "Hyperbolic geometry" by J.Anderson and "Geometry of discrete groups" by A.Beardon.

In the book Geometry of Discrete groups has same to same proof  like Katok's Book.

I doubt this. What page?

Page 219 , Section 9.3 point 7

Now read carefully what Beardon says and compare it to what Katok says. Beardon's claim is correct while Katok's is false (in more than one way). My guess is that Katok was repeating Beardon's text without reading the "fine print."
